# Admin Breaks When Using Jinja2

Tags: jinja2, wagtail

For some reason my wagtail admin interface is breaking when I try and use Jinja2 as my template engine instead of Django Template Engine. My frontend works just fine, it finds my templates in app/jinja2. This is a Django project with wagtail added on.

Here is the error that I am getting when trying to access /admin,

```
TemplateDoesNotExist at /admin/wagtailadmin/home.html
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/
Django Version: 1.11
Exception Type: TemplateDoesNotExist
Exception Value: wagtailadmin/home.html
Exception Location: /Users/dbroadlick/Desktop/projects/codero2/virtualenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/loader.py in get_template, line 25
Python Executable:  /Users/dbroadlick/Desktop/projects/codero2/virtualenv/bin/python
Python Version: 3.6.1
Python Path:    ['/Users/dbroadlick/Desktop/projects/codero2',
 '/Users/dbroadlick/Desktop/projects/codero2/virtualenv/lib/python36.zip',
 '/Users/dbroadlick/Desktop/projects/codero2/virtualenv/lib/python3.6',
 '/Users/dbroadlick/Desktop/projects/codero2/virtualenv/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload',
 '/Users/dbroadlick/Desktop/projects/codero2/virtualenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages']
Server time:    Mon, 24 Jul 2017 21:40:59 +0000
```

Here is what my template configuration looks like,

```
TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.jinja2.Jinja2',
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'extensions': [
            'wagtail.wagtailcore.jinja2tags.core',
            'wagtail.wagtailadmin.jinja2tags.userbar',
            'wagtail.wagtailimages.jinja2tags.images',
        ],
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
        ],
    },
},
]
```

It also says it is trying to use the jinja2 engine which it should not because wagtail admin is programmed using Django templates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `TEMPLATES` setting has Jinja2 configured as the only available template engine, so there's nothing to trigger the 'traditional' Django Template engine behaviour that the Wagtail admin relies on (namely: to look inside each app's `/template` folder for the requested template path `wagtailadmin/home.html`). As a result, the template never gets found. You need to include configurations for both Jinja2 and DjangoTemplates in your `TEMPLATES` setting - something like:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.jinja2.Jinja2',
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'extensions': [
                'wagtail.wagtailcore.jinja2tags.core',
                'wagtail.wagtailadmin.jinja2tags.userbar',
                'wagtail.wagtailimages.jinja2tags.images',
            ],
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Note that you'll need to have some convention in place to tell Django which templates should be rendered with which engine - with the above configuration, I believe that putting your Jinja2 templates inside `some_app/jinja2/` rather than `some_app/templates/` should take care of that.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you sir. This should probably be noted in Wagtail's documentation, http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.9/advanced_topics/jinja2.html. Its quite reliant on your Django knowledge.